# Bash: Curl multiple lines, write output to file

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script that call cURL with several params.

I need to write the output in a file (also overwriting). But I cannot do.

The call itself works, but I have only an empty file (and the answer is a json, I can read on the shell with that echo)

Thank you in advance for your help

1st try

```
 curl -X POST "https://www.example.com"\
        -H "X-Auth-Email: $email"\
        -H "X-Auth-Key: $auth_key"\
        -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
        --data '{"name":"'$name'","surname":"'$surname'"}'
        >> id.txt
        echo
```

2nd try

```
curl -X POST "https://www.example.com"\
            -H "X-Auth-Email: $email"\
            -H "X-Auth-Key: $auth_key"\
            -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
            --data '{"name":"'$name'","surname":"'$surname'"}'
            o id.txt
            echo
```

Comment: Building JSON using string interpolation is fragile. Consider using something like `jq` instead: `--data "$(jq --arg n "$name" --arg sn "$surname" '{name: $n, surname: $sn}')"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -X POST "https://www.example.com"\
        -H "X-Auth-Email: $email"\
        -H "X-Auth-Key: $auth_key"\
        -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
        --data '{"name":"'$name'","surname":"'$surname'"}'\
        -o id.txt
```